# Weird WCF behaviour regarding Timouts and Exceptions

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms

I have created an WCF service hosted inside a normal Windows service. This service is deployed to customers and set up on their servers. Therefore (afaik) I need to establish the WCF proxy dynamically and cannot rely on some prebuilt proxy created by VS or the Silverlight tools. The clients in this case are mobile apps built with Xamarin.Forms.
The Code to create the "Channel":

```
public void Init(int timeout = 15)
{
    ea = new EndpointAddress(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/{2}", _settingsService.ConnectionIP, _settingsService.ConnectionPort, _settingsService.ConnectionEndpoint));
    bhttpb = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
    bhttpb.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);

    cfIMMC = new ChannelFactory<IMaintMobileContract>(bhttpb, ea);
    cfIMMC.Opened += cfIMMC_Opened;
    cfIMMC.Faulted += cfIMMC_Faulted;
    cfIMMC.Closed += cfIMMC_Closed;

    immc = cfIMMC.CreateChannel(ea);
    immc.Ping(); // This function is defined by me in the Contract. It only returns true, if the server can be reached.
}
```

So far everything works fine if the service is running, but the app has to run "offline" and then it gets weird.
When the connection is established there is no `EndpointException` or anything, and when a function is called it just sits there waiting until the timeout hits.
It would be really nice to get some information whether the WCF service is actually there or not. I have function calls that can take up to multiple minutes and it would be fatal for the app to wait that long when the WCF server is not there at all. How can I achieve that?

**Update:**
Right now it got even weirder. Now, aprox. 30 seconds after the `Ping()` fails, I get `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection timed out` and `System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out)` out of nowhere.

**Update 2 :**
Here a pic of the CallStack:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need fast feedback regarding whether service is alive or not, then setup additional endpoint (with separate contract containing only `Ping` method) and set small timeouts for it.
And important part is to set send/receive timeouts to small value as well - this will ensure that `Ping` method returns/throws fast if service is not available.

As far as I remember WCF does not open channel (== does not connect to server) until you call one of the methods - that's why you don't have exceptions before `Ping` is called.

About exception after 30 seconds. Where do you see it? I mean is it Visual Studio that breaks there or do you have your application failing with unhandled exception? I'm asking it because I see this in the Xamarin/Mono code:

```
initConn = new WaitCallback (state => {
    try {
        InitConnection (state);
    } catch {}
});
```

And it means that even though this exception is thrown after 30 seconds - it'll be swallowed. What really happens is that when request is sent (i.e. when you call `Ping()`) the runtime tries to open connection in background (your call stack confirms that) and 30 seconds is default Windows timeout for connection. WCF will fail earlier if it has lower timeout set (like in your case), but connection attempt will last for 30 seconds and will complete with exception.

So, my opinion is that you should not care about this exception, unless it somehow stops your application.

Comment: The problem is, I don't get a stack trace. It doesn't even show me a line in my code. The only thing I can provide is the Call stack. I've updated my Question.

Comment: So first, I solved this almost the same way you suggested but I did it with the very same contract and just another channel with timouts at 500 ms. Second, it was VS that broke there and told me that there was an exception. But now I've switched from VS15 to 17 and it is gone. (I suspect some Exception settings were wrong). And third, it is always good to know some internal things about the frameworks we are using, thanks for that insight.